# Auto scroll to bottom not working, when zoomed in/out (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I've made an autoscroll to bottom in a section with this javascript code, and this code are working properly when page zoom is 100%.

```
this.chatHistoryScrollRef.mainWrapperRef.scrollTop = this.chatHistoryScrollRef.mainWrapperRef.scrollHeight
```

But when the page are zoomed in/out (!= 100%), this code are not working. The autoscroll to bottom is not working.

I've check the `scrollTop` when it zoomed in/out it becomes a fraction instead of an integer.

i.e the `scrollTop` property when page are 100% is 4800, but when zoomed in/out it becomes 4800.931203.

[scrollTop & scrollHeight when zoomed in/out](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SQ8wc.png)